# Is it safe to encrypt website configuration with RSA/RSA+AES and store in source code?

Tags: security, encryption, configuration, cryptography, rsa

As you probably know, it is very bad to store software configuration like database passwords in source code. We can use environment variables for all our configuration, but it will require to create dozens of variables and it is not easy to use with our cloud provider. My idea is to use `RSA` to encrypt all configuration keys separately like this:

```
// config.json file:
{
    "databasePassword": "k32noi23fj3209jf23...",
    "awsKey": "qKwmkwfl3j2P?38...",
    "smtpPassword": "23kKS293j..."
}
```

Then, decrypt each value with decryption key:

```
var decryptionKey = GetSystemEnvironmentVariable("DecryptionKey");
var encryptedDbPassword = ReadConfigSetting("databasePassword");
var decryptedDbPassword = RsaDecrypt(decryptionKey, encryptedDbPassword);
```

So I only need one environment variable/file to decrypt all keys in configuration and the key will not be in source code or available to employees.

How safe is 4096 bit `RSA` for such task? If someone steal my config file without decryption key, will it be possible to recalculate my decryption key with reasonable amount of computing power? And if not safe enough, can I use 2 cithers, for example encrypt with `RSA` first, then with `AES` using another key?

Comment: A server needs to access the configuration, so it needs the key for that, right? Why do you think that this is better than not encrypting at all? Can you describe your system architecture and who encrypts when?

Comment: I will generate both encryption/decryption keys and manually encrypt each value in the config file for production environment. So, the encryption key is only available for me and decryption key will only be available to me and on the production server as environment variable.

Comment: Then this doesn't seem to add any real security. This is just more security through obscurity, because the decryption key must be close to the ciphertexts.

Comment: I use amazon AWS and do the following.  I put my keys and secure configs into a tar file.  I then use RSA 4096 to lock things up.  The decryption key is applied by a script.  The script takes the decryption key as an argument that is copy/pasted into the AWS "User Data".  The script takes the key, then downloads the file from S3, then uses the key on the downloaded file.  At no time does it store the key, it just becomes an argument to the script that is launched.

Comment: @ArtjomB. It will make deployment process easier, because we can add more keys to config without touching our production environment (config file will be automatically uploaded with deployment, but not system variables). We also cannot use more than 5 environment variables and we have much more parameters than this - this will require to combine multiple settings into one, all with manual work and prone to errors.

Comment: Then it seems like you have a plan. Note that you don't need RSA at all. AES is sufficient here, because if an RSA private is lost, the corresponding public key can be directly created from that in case you want to prevent tampering.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, having read your comments, I think it makes sense and it depends on your risk appetite. It definitely adds some risk and a few threats to consider (as detailed below), but it doesn't sound fundamentally flawed to me.

A few thoughts:

- Storing your parameters encrypted in source code gives an attacker that has access to your source code an infinite amount of time and resources to crack the encryption, at least from a theoretical point of view. An attacker may try to build a large cluster of parallelized decryption nodes and may also exploit flaws of your chosen encryption algorithm discovered in the future.
- Closely related to that, one caveat of encrypting stuff is usually key management. You should sometimes change encryption keys, partly to mitigate this risk above. If it takes longer for the attacker to crack your key than the interval that you change it, you're good.
- You should also change the secrets contained in your configuration regularly. This again mitigates another aspect of the risk that an attacker might be able to break your encryption.
- I would choose an algorithm that is slow (computationally intensive) to decrypt. While Artjom B. is right that you don't technically need public key crypto for this purpose, I would probably go with RSA anyway, because that could be more CPU power for an offline attacker to bruteforce (also depending on key lengths).
- I would choose a relatively large key, 4096 bit RSA looks good.

In short, in my security hat I don't quite like this solution, but depending on your scenario and usecases, you may decide to accept the risk.